# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'result[0].geometry')

Tags: angular, google-maps, angular5, geolocalización

Hola estoy tratando de obtener la latitud y longitug en angular y se guarde en firebase me da este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código es:

> import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
>   import { LugaresService } from '../services/lugares.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-crear',
  templateUrl: './crear.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./crear.component.css']
})
export class CrearComponent {
  lugar: any = {};
  constructor(private lugaresService: LugaresService) {
  }
  guardarLugar() {

```
var direccion = this.lugar.calle+','+ this.lugar.ciudad+','+this.lugar.pais;
this.lugaresService.obtenerGeoData(direccion)
.subscribe((result) => {
  this.lugar.lat = result[0].geometry.location.lat;
  this.lugar.lng = result[0].geometry.location.lng;
  this.lugar.id = Date.now();
  this.lugaresService.guardarLugar(this.lugar);
  alert('Indicio guardado con exito');
  this.lugar = {};
});

var direccion = this.lugar.calle+','+ this.lugar.ciudad+','+this.lugar.pais;
this.lugaresService.obtenerGeoData(direccion)
    .subscribe((result) =>{
      this.lugar.lat = this.lugar.lat = result[0].geometry.location.lat;;
      this.lugar.lng = this.lugar.lng = result[0].geometry.location.lng;
      this.lugar.id = Date.now();
      this.lugaresService.guardarLugar(this.lugar);
      alert('Indicio guardado con exito');
      this.lugar = {};
    });
```

}

}

/*

y asi llamo el servicio

> ```
> public obtenerGeoData(direccion) {
> ```

```
    return this.http.get('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + direccion + '&key=<tu api key>'   );

}
```

Comment: Puedes compartir el contenido de tu result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No obtenia nada en el result ya que el api de google maps lo tenia en http y lo cambie a https asi mismo le concatene mi api key asi: `'https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + direccion + '&key=<Aqui tu apiKey>'`
despues puse un debugger para ver que contenia result, así mire que ya obtenia la geolocalizacion y atra vez de la consola navegue hasta obtener la latitud y longuitud terminando asi:

```
 var direccion = this.lugar.calle +','+ this.lugar.ciudad +','+ this.lugar.pais;
   this.lugarService
     .obtenerGeoData(direccion)
       .subscribe( (result:any) => {
         debugger;
         this.lugar.lat = result.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
         this.lugar.lng = result.results[0].geometry.location.lng;

         if (this.id != 'new') {
           this.lugarService.guardarLugar(this.lugar)
           // alert('¡Negocio editado con exito!')
           swal({
             type: 'success',
             title: 'Indicio editado con exito!',
           })
```